# Why does my Apple wireless keyboard get disconnected from my Macbook Pro?

Tags: wireless-keyboard

My Apple wireless keyboard started acting weird. After I replaced its batteries two days ago, it has been getting disconnected every few hours. When the disconnection happens, if I'm typing something, the operating system will just hold the last key I had pushed until I can reconnect the keyboard again.

Is this related to the new batteries I added? I checked the preferences menu, and the batteries are showing over 50% full.

Comment: Did you try rebooting everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's [interference](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1365).